# How to propery update an image in Nativescript?

Tags: angularjs, image, nativescript

I have the requirement to update an image in the App over and over again (displaying some generated data).
But after several intervals the app crashes with out of memory.

I'm updating the image with this line:

> (that.detailImage.nativeElement).src = DummyImage.image1;

setting the image as base64-String. I already tried using res:// and external references and even local files. The problem stays: it keeps the memory.

Reducing the size of the image helps only to delay the crash, I even got the crash with an 1kb image, but it took some minutes.

You can find the "running" code at:
https://bitbucket.org/WarEagle/implementationproblems/src/944eedf10a14d60ec421e274760b3c2c3d9ae9a1/ImageTest/?at=master

I'm really interested in understanding what I'm doing wrong. Every solution I found so far said: "make the image smaller" but this only delays the problem.

Greetings

Torsten

p.s. don't wonder about the = undefined in the example-code, this is done because I'm setting the same image over and over again, than it works, but if I update the src-property with another image, it crashes, for this example I used = undefined to reproduce the problem without uploading thousands of images for changing them around.

Comment: Have you looked into solutions like nativescript-fresco for Android (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-fresco). Image handling on mobile and especially on Android is still a huge issue that does not have a built-in solution in the Android framework itself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I didn't look into it. This solves my problem for Android, but because it doesn't map to the normal image, I have to create a switch for every image in my app when using this, because you cannot use fresco on ios :(

Comment: Just for completion, I splitted up the ui into something.android.html and something.ios.html and managed the images differently. Seems to work fine. Thanks for your suggestion.